# Greasemonkey script to upload multiple images?

Tags: scripting, greasemonkey

I have an account at wikidot.com that hosts wikis for free.

they will even store up to 300mb per of images for you. I currently have a car repair wiki that is doing quite well but I have to upload all the pictures one at a time.

I know that this is probably a good application where Greasemonkey could help me but I have very little experience with it.

Can anyone give me some good starter information on how I would upload multiple files ( by multiple I mean upload one then have the script loop and up load the next, etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing, I actually think Greasemonkey might not be the best choice, but would rather recommend taking a look at [Rightload](http://rightload.org).

It should be rather simple to make your own configuration for uploading to Wikia, and with that, you should be able to easily batch-upload a bunch of pictures.

Comment: Not sure if thats going to work but it might be the best option i have